# Override method magento 2

Tags: overrides, plugin, magento2.4.3

I am using magento 2.4.3 EE version

Is their any way to override below method

```
    protected function _calculate($rule, $item, $qty, $rulePercent)

for below classes

\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::TO_PERCENT_ACTION =>
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\ToPercent::class,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION =>
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\ByPercent::class,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::TO_FIXED_ACTION => \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\ToFixed::class,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION => \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\ByFixed::class,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION =>
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CartFixed::class,
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::BUY_X_GET_Y_ACTION =>
\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\BuyXGetY::class,
```

The **_calculate** method is common method for the above classes.
I want to add some code in all these class to make changes in all cart rules.

Is there anyway to do within module ?
I know about extending class & use of plugins so some idea needed on modifying this method for all classes at once.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: In the future, you might consider adding the specific M2 version tag to your question. Saves time if we know exactly where to look.

Comment: updated tag in question.

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to take a second look at these classes. From my review of them, only `ByPercent` contains a protected `_calculate($rule, $item, $qty, $rulePercent)` method that would require a class extension. `ToPercent` extends from `ByPercent`, so overriding that method should resolve both.

As for the other classes, they appear only to have public `calculate($rule, $item, $qty)` methods, so a single plugin should suffice if you need to modify it in all classes. If you're really only interested in the protected method, though, than a single class extension of `ByPercent` is all you need.

Comment: So, the discount is set from the calculate($rule, $item, $qty) method for these options in rule (Percent of product price discount,Fixed amount discount,Fixed amount discount for whole cart,Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y)) right ?

Comment: I would say yes. The public `calculate($rule, $item, $qty)` methods all seem to do the heavy lifting for discount calculation in ToFixed, ByFixed, CartFixed, and BuyXGetY. The protected `_calculate($rule, $item, $qty, $rulePercent)` method does the heavy lifting in ByPercent, and in ToPercent because the latter extends from the former.